# Already declared variable shows 'variable used before declaration'

Tags: swift, variables, declaration

I 'fixed' a previous error but doing so ended up having it say 'variable "answer" being used before declaration' when I clearly declared it. What's wrong with the code?

```
    if operation.text == "/" {
            identifyVal()
            var answer:Float = 0.0 // declared the value of answer
            answer = round(Float(randomNumber)/Float(randomNumber2))
        }

        var answer:UInt32
        if operation.text == "+" {
            answer = randomNumber + randomNumber2 //nothing wrong
        }
        if operation.text == "-" {
            identifyVal()
            answer = randomNumber - randomNumber2 
        }
        if operation.text == "x" {
            answer = randomNumber * randomNumber2 
        }
        secretAnsarrrrr.text = String(answer) //error
        numA.text = String(Int(randomNumber))
        numB.text = String(Int(randomNumber2))
```

The other part of the code being:

```
    if optionAnswer == 0 {
        optionA.text = secretAnsarrrrr.text // nothing wrong
    }
```

How do I fix this?

Here's a screenshot of where I put my UILabel 'secretAnsarrrr'

[image: sizeclassesenable]

As you can see secretAnsarr appears when size classes is enabled, but when I disable it it becomes invisible.
[image: sizeclassesdisable]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare your `answer` this way:

```
var answer:UInt32?
```

And your error will solved.

**UPDATE:**

```
    var answer:Float = 0.0
    if operation.text == "/" {

    }

    if operation.text == "+" {

    }
    if operation.text == "-" {

    }
    if operation.text == "x" {

    }
    secretAnsarrrrr.text = "\(answer)"
```

Comment: That will give an error to the line after I declare 'answer', the rounding part

Comment: Cannot assign a type '(Float)' to a value of  type 'UInt32?'

Comment: yes because your answer type is `UInt32 ` and you are assigning it `Float ` value.

Comment: I must use Float because I'm rounding it, I'm generating two random numbers and when I divide them, I must make sure they are not repetitive decimals and so. For example 10/3 must be rounded to 3.

Comment: If you want it as `Float ` then why you declare it with type `UInt32 `?

Comment: You told me to declare it as UInt32?, I originally had float but got that problem

Comment: I have updated answer and declare your answer that way.

Comment: variable "answer" being used before being initialized

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84137/discussion-between-justsoft-and-dharmesh-kheni).

Comment: Do you need anything?

Answer (score 0):

In that part:

```
var answer:UInt32
        if operation.text == "+" {
            answer = randomNumber + randomNumber2 //nothing wrong
        }
        if operation.text == "-" {
            identifyVal()
            answer = randomNumber - randomNumber2 
        }
        if operation.text == "x" {
            answer = randomNumber * randomNumber2 
        }
```

If `operation.text` is not +, - or x `answer` will be nil. You have two options - whether to set initial value to answer:

```
var answer:UInt32 = 0
```

Or to make it optional and unwrap it afterwards:

```
var answer:UInt32?
    if operation.text == "+" {
        answer = randomNumber + randomNumber2 //nothing wrong
    }
    if operation.text == "-" {
        identifyVal()
        answer = randomNumber - randomNumber2 
    }
    if operation.text == "x" {
        answer = randomNumber * randomNumber2 
    }
    if let answer = answer
    {
         secretAnsarrrrr.text = String(answer) //error
    }
```